# StartService Gives me error 2 The System Can't Find The File Specified

Tags: c++, kmdf

StartService gives me "error 2 The System Can't Find The File Specified"

I can't determine if my driver is messing up or if it's my user application. Here is what I am doing:

```
schService = CreateService(schSCManager, DriverName, DriverName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS | SERVICE_START | DELETE | SERVICE_STOP, SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, SERVICE_DEMAND_START, SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE, SYSTEM32_DRIVERS, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (schService == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error CreateService : %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    schService = OpenService(schSCManager, DriverName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
    StartService(schService, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: At what code line does the error occur? Maybe a dependent Dll isn't in the current directory and also not in the search path? Try using a dependency walker tool.

Comment: What's `SYSTEM32_DRIVERS`?

Comment: Its the location to my sys32 drivers and than my driver

Comment: I think it has to do with my driver I will have a look and report back if it still says error 2.

Comment: So now I got rid of error 2, but now comes up another one yay! The error is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
87 (0x57)
The parameter is incorrect. It is directed towards start service, I debugged it.